# Get key from map and retrieve data with it in one query

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in mongo. First, is the actual data:

```
{ "_id" : "internal_key1", "data" : "some data1" }
{ "_id" : "internal_key2", "data" : "some data2" }
{ "_id" : "internal_key3", "data" : "some data3" }
```

Another one is a map of keys as provided by some external service to my internal keys:

```
{ "_id" : "ext_key111", "internal" : "internal_key1" }
{ "_id" : "ext_key222", "internal" : "internal_key2" }
{ "_id" : "ext_key333", "internal" : "internal_key3" }
```

If I only have external key, can I somehow retrieve data (for example, given "ext_key111" retrieve "some data1") with just one query? Not counting eval-like stuff, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

You are basically asking for a join and MongoDB explicitly does not allow joins.

*However*, depending on your requirements, you may be able to get away with the following structure:

```
{ "_id" : "internal_key1", "ext_id": "ext_key111", "data" : "some data1" }
```

You can create an additional index on `ext_id`. You can even make it unique which seems to match your data.

```
db.ensureIndex({ ext_id: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
```

Comment: Now I don't have to write my own answer, since this is exactly the solution I've turned to.