# Full Outer join in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, outer-join, nosql

I want to do a Full Outer Join in MongoDB by lookup mongoDB query. Is this possible? Is a Full Outer Join supported by MongoDB by any other alternative?

[Update:]

I want to achieve result from Collection1 & Collection2 as following attachment:

Example: [Result Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmERw.jpg)

In above result column there may be different arithmetic operations and will be further used in calculations.

Comment: Not yet. Wait for MongoDB 3.6 where you can do an "non-correlated" `$lookup`. But rather than say "you need it" you should instead be justifying "why". Because even with the facility to "join" you will get far better application performance by designing in such a way where no such thing is required.

Comment: Hello Neil, I have attached sample collections and required result. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use $unionWith (starting 4.4)
Something like this:

```
db.c1.aggregate([
{$set: {
  mark1: "$marks"
}}, 
{$unionWith: {
  coll: 'c2',
  pipeline: [{$set: {mark2: "$marks"}}]
}}, 
{$group: {
  _id: "$name",
  result: {
    $sum: "$marks"
  },
  mark1: {$first: {$ifNull: ["$mark1", 0]}},
  mark2: {$first: {$ifNull: ["$mark2", 0]}}
}}])
```

Answer (score 3):

I have named the collections as coll1 and coll2 then just use this query it will give you the required output.

```
db.getCollection('coll1').aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            commonRecords: [{
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "coll2",
                        localField: 'name',
                        foreignField: 'name',
                        as: "coll2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: {
                        path: '$coll2',
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "coll2",
            let: {
                names: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$commonRecords',
                        as: 'commonRecord',
                        in: '$$commonRecord.name'
                    }
                }
            },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: [{
                            $indexOfArray: ['$$names', '$name']
                        }, -1]
                    }
                }
            }, ],
            as: "coll2"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            coll2: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$coll2',
                    as: 'doc',
                    in: {
                        coll2: '$$doc'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            records: {
                $concatArrays: ['$commonRecords', '$coll2']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$records'
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: '$records'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: {
                $ifNull: ['$name', '$coll2.name']
            },
            marks1: {
                $ifNull: ['$marks', 0]
            },
            marks2: {
                $ifNull: ['$coll2.marks', 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            result: {
                $add: ['$marks1', '$marks2']
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I think adding proper explanation also will help viewers

Answer (score 1):

It is supported only after version 4.4 to $unionWith.

```js
db.col1.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { 
      from: "col2", 
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "name", 
      as: "detail" 
  }},
  { $unwind: { 
      path: "$detail", 
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }}, 
  { $project: { 
      name: 1,
      marks: "$marks",
      marks2: "$detail.marks" 
   }},
   { $unionWith: {
     coll: "col2",
     pipeline: [{
       $addFields: { marks: 0, marks2: "$marks" }
     }]
   }},
   { $group: { 
     _id: "$name", 
     marks:{ $first: "$marks" }, 
     marks2: { $first: "$marks2"},
   }},
   { $project: { 
      _id: 1,
      marks: 1,
      marks2: {$ifNull: ["$marks2", 0]},
      total: {$add: [ {$ifNull: ["$marks", 0]}, {$ifNull: ["$marks2", 0]} 
     ]},
   }}
])
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a sample:

```
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: [collection to join],
           local_Field: [field from the input documents],
           foreign_Field: [field from the documents of the "from" collection],
           as: [output field]
         }
    }
```

show [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563762/join-two-collections-in-mongodb/62988605#62988605) link