# mongodb - perform batch query

Tags: mongodb

I need query data from collection a first, then according to those data, query from collection b. Such as:

```
For each id queried from a
    query data from b where "_id" == id
```

In SQL, this can be done by join table a & b in a single select. But in mongodb, it needs do multi query, it seems inefficient, doesn't it? Or it can be done by just 2 queries?(one for a, another for b, rather than 1 plus n) I know NoSQL doesn't support join, but is there a way to batch execute queries in for loop into a single query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to do it as two steps.

Look into the `$in` operator ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)) which allows passing an array of `_id`s for example. Many would suggest you do those in batches of, say, 1000 `_id`s.

```
db.myCollection.find({ _id : { $in : [ 1, 2, 3, 4] }})
```

Comment: is it not inefficient when mongodb is hosted on remote network and number of document id's are of considerable high amout as it it will take double bandwidth first to load and than to upload

Comment: @RavinderPayal-inefficient compared to what? Sometimes MongoDB solutions require creative document design to avoid unnecessary work. And, more importantly, it's not always the best choice for a database.

Comment: i asking this because i am currently developing social network platform and let a user have 1000 friends saved in mongodb now to find posts by those 1000 friends i need to load id's of those 1000 peoples from remote db and now need to reupload that data to that remote db which contains posts

Comment: Whichever works for you best: one call with a high payload, or 1000 calls with a low payload.

Comment: Yes its ineffecient to do this as two queries, this is an old answer perhaps it was the only way at the time but today you would use $lookup.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, don't make so many DB calls for each id, it is very inefficient, it is possible to execute a single query which will return all documents relevant to each of the ids in a single pass using the **$in** operator in MongoDB, which is synonymous to **in** syntax  in SQL so for example if you need to find out the documents for 5 ids in a single pass then

```
const ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'];
const results = db.collectionName.find({ _id : { $in : ids }})
```

This will get you all the relevant documents in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `join` in SQL parlance and you can do it in mongo using an aggregate query called [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup).

For example if you had some types in collections like these:

```js
interface IFoo {
  _id: ObjectId
  name: string
}
interface IBar {
  _id: ObjectId
  fooId: ObjectId
  title: string
}
```

Then query with an aggregate like this:

```js
await db.foos.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: { $in: ids } } // query criteria here
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'bars',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'fooId',
      as: 'bars'
    }
  }
])
```

May produce resulting objects like this:

```json
{
  "_id": "foo0",
  "name": "example foo",
  "bars": [
    { _id: "bar0", "fooId": "foo0", title: "crow bar" }
  ]
}
```