# How to fetch data in a single go from mongodb based on multiple filters?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I am new to mongodb and aggregation framework.

We have a class UserMetaData and a list of UserMetaData. I need to fetch data according to the userMetaDataList that is passed to the method solve().
Currently I am iterating the list and one by one fetching the corresponding collection from the monogdb. Since the db calls are made for each element in the list, this becomes a highly expensive operation.
Is there any way to fetch all the required data from mongodb in one shot(more like a bulk fetch operation).

[mongodb - perform batch query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661774/mongodb-perform-batch-query) the solution provided in this does not fulfill the requirements of the current scenario.
Please help!!

This is how I am doing currently.

```
class UserMetaData{
    String userId;
    String vehicleId;
    String vehicleColour;
    String orderId;
}

public List<String> getOrderIds(List<UserMetaData> userMetaDataList) {
    List<String> orderIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (UserMetaData userMetadata : userMetaDataList) {
        try {
            BasicDBObject matchDBObject = new BasicDBObject("user_id", new BasicDBObject("$eq", userMetadata.getUserId()));
            matchDBObject.append("vehicle_id", new BasicDBObject("$eq", userMetadata.getVehicleID()));
            matchDBObject.append("vehicle_colour", new BasicDBObject("$in", ImmutableSet.of("WHITE", "BLACK")));
            Document document = eventCollection.find(matchDBObject)
                    .projection(new BasicDBObject("order_id", "1"))
                    .first();
            orderIds.add(document.get("order_id").toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception occurred while fetching order id for user_id: {} asset_id:{} - {}", metadata.getUserId(), metadata.getAssetID(), e);
        }
    }
    return ordersIds;
}
```

I want to fetch all the corresponding data in a single query.
Requesting help.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all filters with $OR condition and fetch the full list at once ...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fetch all the corresponding data in a single query.

You can use this approach and perform the query as a single operation (avoids the for-loop).

Consider sample documents in the collection `test`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("621762e2cda7c6394d557f37"), "userid" : 1, "name" : "ijk", "orderid" : "11" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("621762efcda7c6394d557f38"), "userid" : 12, "name" : "abc", "orderid" : "99" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("621762fccda7c6394d557f39"), "userid" : 13, "name" : "xyz", "orderid" : "100" }
```

The array of objects to filter:

```
var DOCS = [
  { userid: 12, name: "abc" },
  { userid: 13, name: "xyz" }
]
```

The query to filter by `DOCS`:

```
db.test.find( 
  {
    $expr: { 
      $in: [ { userid: "$userid", name: "$name" },  DOCS ]
    }
  },
  { 
    orderid: 1
  }
)
```

The output has documents with `userid`s `12` and `13`.

**[ EDIT - ADD ]**

This **aggregation** an improvement over the `find`:

```
db.test.aggregate([

  // This matches the 'userid' and 'name' fields with the input list 'DOCS'
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { 
              $in: [ { userid: "$userid", name: "$name" },  DOCS ]
          }
      }
  },

  // The grouping will select only the first matching for the 'userid' and 'name'
  // (this is as per the question post's code: `.first()`)
  {
      $group: { 
          _id: { 
             userid: "$userid", 
             name: "$name" 
          }, 
          orderid: { 
              $first: "$orderid" 
          }
      }
  },

  // Remove the '_id' field
  // Now the result has just the 'orderid' field only
  { 
      $unset: "_id" 
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I strongly believe that this should work. But the thing is that $expr is supported in mongo 3.6+. Could you please help with the way to achieve the same in lower version than mongo 3.6. (essentially without $expr).

Comment: The `$expr` is introduced with MongoDB v 3.6. See the [v3.6 Release Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/release-notes/3.6/#new-query-operators).