# How can one "join" a DBRef

Tags: mongodb, dbref

Somehow it must be possbile to generate a result when DBReferences are resolved and the value of the referenced object is given back together whit the original object.

example: first object has a reference

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53bd526a5894ca07e60ca414"),
"name": "The name"
"labelnames" : {

    "de" : {
        "$ref" : "nameList",
        "$id" : ObjectId("53bd526a5894ca07e60ca41c")
    }
}
}
```

Second objects stores the value

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53bd526a5894ca07e60ca41c"),
"lang" : "de",
"labelNameMap" : {
    "9d96cd10-d27f-4579-9f6e-9fd8d9f9c683" : {
        "value" : "the value"
    }
}
}
```

The result should be:
{name: "The name", value: "the value}
With SQL it would be a join, how ist this done in MongoDB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: well is there no simpler solution for this case?

Comment: No, you cannot query two collections at the same time. Some programming frameworks will hide that from you, but they'll do several queries in background.