# Golang Mgo populate nested structs by ID (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Using mongoose with NodeJs for document population to simulate joins is very common. I'm trying to understand how to achieve something similar with go and mgo.

```
type User struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    UserName string
}

type MessageBoard {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
}

type Tag struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    text string
}

type Post struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Text string
    MessageBoard bson.ObjectId
    User bson.ObjectId
    Tags []bson.ObjectId
}
```

I would like to store only User and Tag ids in Post. A user can have many posts and if the user edits UserName all posts should reflect this.

```
var posts []Post

err := PostCollection.Find(bson.M{"MessageBoard":mBoardId}).All(&posts)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

This is a simple query to get posts, but how do I efficiently get posts with User and Tags models populated?

There is Sleep (an Mgo extension) which appears to do what I am looking for, but I am interested in understanding the performance implications and design options better and if there is a solution using Mgo alone. https://github.com/mansoor-s/Sleep

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following question on Stack Overflow:

[How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

However, it's not always necessary to simulate joins for a NoSQL database such as MongoDB. You might want to consider doing an extra query or using cache when you need to get `User` for all `Post`s.

P.S. Even if you are using SQL database, `JOIN` statement should be carefully reviewed and is not recommended on production, because of its potential performance issue.