# One to one relationship between tables mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a one to one relationship between two tables.How to do this?I've read documentation but there is only some examples.I think i should do something on schema.Thanks for help

Comment: There is currently too little information to decide exactly what you want. However, for basic JOINs have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563205/how-to-join-query-in-mongodb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546983/join-for-collection-in-mongodb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once ? If so can you be more exact about what your problem is?

Comment: I have two tables.When i save something inn one of them mongo gives me an id ....When i save in the first table i save something in the table no 2..i want to have the same id like in the first table in the table no 2