# MapReduce mongodb: ReferenceError

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have this collection in mongodb:

```
articles = {

{
        id: 102
        pagelinks: { 104, 105, 107, 108 },
        title: "page1"
},

{
        id: 104
        pagelinks: { 102, 205, 207, 108 },
        title: "page2"
},

...
}
```

I want to have this collection:

page_link_titles= {

```
{
        id: 102,
        links: { "page2", "page5", "page7", "page9"}            
},

{
        id: 104,
        links: { "page1", "page5", "page7", "page9" }            
},

...
}
```

I am using [mapreduce](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/02/03/joins-now-possible-in-mongodb-2-4/) in this way:

```
var map = function () {
                var output= {links:db.articles.find({id : {$in: db.articles.findOne({id:this.id}).pagelinks}}, {title: 1, _id:0})}
                    emit(this.id, output);
                };
var reduce = function(key, values) {
                var outs={ links:null}
                values.forEach(function(v){                    
                    if(outs.links ==null){
                        outs.links = v.links
                    }                     
                });
                return outs;
            };
```

db.articles.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: 'page_link_titles'});

and I get this error:

```
    mapreduce failed: { 
        "errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined near 't={links:db.articles.find({id: {$in: [d' (line2)", 
        "code" : 16722, 
        "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell//collection.js:1224
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that even valid JSON?

Comment: Do this instead of map reduce http://stackoverflow.com/a/22739813/2949810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code snippet:

**Sample collection:**

```
db.articles.insert([
    {
        _id: 102,
        pagelinks: [ 104, 105, 107, 108 ],
        title: "page1"
    },
    {
        _id: 104,
        pagelinks: [ 102, 205, 207, 108 ],
        title: "page2"
    },
    {
        _id: 105,
        pagelinks: [ 102, 205, 207, 104 ],
        title: "page3"
    },    
    {
        _id: 107,
        pagelinks: [ 105, 205, 207, 104 ],
        title: "page3"
    }
]);
```

**The magic:**

```
db.articles.find().forEach( function (doc){
    var obj = { 
        "_id": doc._id 
    };
    var links = [];
    doc.pagelinks.forEach( function (x){
        var result = db.articles.findOne({ "_id": x });       
        if(result && result.title)  links.push(result.title);            
    }); 

    obj["links"] = links.filter(function (value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });
    db.page_link_titles.save(obj);       
});
```

**The result:**

```
db.page_link_titles.find();

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 102,
    "links" : [ "page2", "page3" ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 104,
    "links" : [ "page1" ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 105,
    "links" : [ "page1", "page2" ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 107,
    "links" : [ "page3", "page2" ]
}
```

Comment: I did this: stackoverflow.com/a/22739813/2949810

Comment: db.articles.find().forEach(
    function (newArticle) {        
        newArticle.pagelinks = db.articles.find( { "_id": { $in: newArticle.pagelinks }}, {title: 1, _id:0}   ).toArray();
  newArticle.text = null;
        db.page_linkTitles.insert(newArticle);
    }
);

Comment: With the one I did, all pagelinks are empty :(, I am trying your way.

Comment: @Andi Do you have a sample collection that I can test on from this end? I tested with the sample above and works just fine.

Comment: It's wikipedia collection.

Comment: @Andi I meant sample documents that have the same schema as above?

Comment: Okay it's very strange, it works with the example but not with the real data. Example of document: { "id": 502360, "pagelinks": 21650, 30869108, 22598261, ...}, "title": "Mitchell College"} and I found out that some of the ids in the pagelinks might not exist in articles. For example there is no page with id 22598261. It took me 2 days to find that out :P

Comment: But I see in your code that you check that! I am looking for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

- the map function can **not** reference an other collection and/or
  operations on an other collection see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) : and more
  specifically here where it is stated loud and clear [The map function
  should not access the database for any reason](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd)

Comment: What is the difference between this example and mine? I didn't get your point.

Comment: my point is " The map function should not access the database for any reason" and the db.articles.find ... is trying to access the db.
I don't know about this example or what version that was supposed to be running but read on the comments other people are getting same error as you get and he never explains how to avoid. Anyway this is not the way map reduce works in mongoDB. You can only reference current document with this.XXX and any variables you pass it with scope option.

Comment: hm I got it "Since mongo 2.4, this functionality was removed. To use this functionality, you have to install Mongo 2.2.3."  :-)  http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/02/03/joins-now-possible-in-mongodb-2-4/

Comment: Any way even then this could not be feasible in a production environment since it it is very expensive to call find() for each and every document. If you want to do a join with MR you have to make 2 MR passes one for each collection and use of  'reduce' in second output.