# How to populate a referenced document from other collection and query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the sample collections for the query, I want the result like given below. How can I show the details of device and user's details in `issuedDevices` collection's document using mongo/nodejs query, please help:

**1. collection user**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Pradeep",
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:03:32.350-06:30")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Steve",
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:04:02.362-06:30")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "name" : "Jonhy",
    "email" : "xyz123@gmail.com",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:04:30.834-06:30")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "name" : "Pinty",
    "email" : "p123@gmail.com",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:05:11.035-06:30")
}
```

**2. collection Devices:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "iPad",
    "owner" : "james"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "iPhone",
    "owner" : "Micheal"
}
```

**3. collection issuedDevices:**

```
 /* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55602058a64447a5071a9a85"),
        "userId" : 1,
        "deviceId" : 1,
        "isReturnd" : false,
        "issuedDateTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:08:16.354-06:30")
    }

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55602065a64447a5071a9a86"),
    "userId" : 2,
    "deviceId" : 1,
    "isReturnd" : true,
    "issuedDateTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:08:29.355-06:30")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5560207da64447a5071a9a87"),
    "userId" : 3,
    "deviceId" : 1,
    "isReturnd" : true,
    "issuedDateTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:08:53.615-06:30")
}
```

I want the result like given below, how can I show the details of device and user's details in `issuedDevices` collection's document using mongo/nodejs query.

**Expected Output**

```
 [
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5560207da64447a5071a9a87"),
        "userId" : 3,
        "deviceId" : 1,
        "userDetails":{
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "Jonhy",
            "email" : "xyz123@gmail.com",
            "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:04:30.834-06:30")
        }
        "deviceDetails":{
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "iPhone",
            "owner" : "Micheal"
        },
        "isReturnd" : true,
        "issuedDateTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T00:08:53.615-06:30")
    }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongodb query that would produce the desired result would use the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method of the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor on `db.issuedDevices` to iterate over the documents and create a new document with the results which is then saved to same collection. The following demonstrates this for user with id 3:

```
db.issuedDevices.find({"userId" : 3}).forEach(function (doc){
      var userDetails = db.user.findOne({"_id": 3});
      var deviceDetails = db.devices.findOne({"_id": doc.deviceId});
      doc.userDetails = userDetails;
      doc.deviceDetails = deviceDetails;
      db.issuedDevices.save(doc);
})
```

Querying the issuedDevices collection `db.issuedDevices.find({"userId" : 3})` would yield:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5560207da64447a5071a9a87"),
    "userId" : 3,
    "deviceId" : 1,
    "isReturnd" : true,
    "issuedDateTime" : ISODate("2015-05-23T06:38:53.615Z"),
    "userDetails" : {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "Jonhy",
        "email" : "xyz123@gmail.com",
        "createDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T06:34:30.834Z")
    },
    "deviceDetails" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "iPad",
        "owner" : "james"
    }
}
```

In Mongoose, this can be done by making nested calls within IssuedDevice model but using [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) as documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects that you can then manipulate, not MongooseDocuments :

```
IssuedDevice.findOne({"userId" : 3}).lean().exec(function (err, doc) {
    User.findOne({"_id": 3}).exec(function (err, user) {
        Devices.findOne({"_id": doc.deviceId}).exec(function (err, device) {
            doc.userDetails = user;
            doc.deviceDetails = device;
            console.log(doc); // <--- gives you the result
        });
    });          
});
```