# Terminal mongo to one-to-many basic examples

Tags: mongodb, join, one-to-many

There are a lot of "[why not JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2350495/287948)" questions here, to understand who to use mongodb... But even the guide at [model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) not show the basic clues...

There are to approaches:

1. generate an array that contains the "embedded data" of the join, to produce "on fly" data. (using `find()` and what more simple algoritm?)
2. use the [db.collection.insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert) to produce "persistent data".

So, **if I am at `mongo` terminal, what the simplest way to do that?**

---

### real-life dataset example

At https://github.com/datasets/country-codes we have

- [country-codes.csv](https://github.com/datasets/country-codes/blob/master/data/country-codes.csv): a table with ~250 rows.
- [datapackage.json](https://github.com/datasets/country-codes/blob/master/datapackage.json): a complex structure with the *country-codes* table metadata, at `resources.schema.fields`.

So, before to do *queries* at `mongo` in the terminal, we can perform something like

```
wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/country-codes/master/data/country-codes.csv
wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/country-codes/master/datapackage.json

mongoimport -d ccodes_db -c ccodes --type csv --file country-codes.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d ccodes_db -c ccodes_meta  datapackage.json  --jsonArray

mongo
show dbs
use ccodes_db
```

So, lets "join" `ccodes_meta` with  `ccodes` collections at `mongo`... *The task is to embed* fields  `name` and `description` (of ccodes_meta) into  the ccodes collection... **With the simplest algorithms** (not need best performance), see itens 1 and 2 of the question.