# Morphia join example

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have two collections, `cars` and `car_colors`, where a "car" *hasA* "color":

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
@Entity
class Car extends AbstractMongoEntity {
    String make
    String model
    CarColor color
}

@Entity
class CarColor extends AbstractMongoEntity {
    String name           // e.g. "Red"
    String label          // e.g. "RED"
    String description    // e.g. "The color red."
}
```

I am using [Morphia 1.0.1](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) to OR/map between these POJO entities and MongoDB data. I am looking for a query/selector/find that will allow me to lookup all the `Cars` with a `CarColor#label` of, say, `'BLUE'`. I believe this involves a JOIN operation somehow, though I'm not seeing how. Here's my best attempt so far which doesn't work:

```
datastore.find(Car).field('color').field('label').equal('BLUE').asList()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: MongoDB is NoSQL database, which means it does not support joins. AFAIK, morphia is just a pretty wrapper over the mongo java driver, which converts documents to the corresponding objects.

Comment: Thank you @NayanjyotiDeka (+1) - yes I guess I mean "join" in a general sense, implying an association between the two collections. At the end of the day, I just need to know how to filter Cars by CarColor. Thanks again!

Comment: Check this out, this might give you some idea how to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22739813/2776345 . Basically for each record you are finding the corresponding object making a query to the dbcollection. Mongo driver for java has option for .forEach() as well. http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/query/

Answer (score 0):

Just use ".", for example,
`datastore.find(Car).field('color.label').equal('BLUE').asList()`