# mongo join between two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have two mongo collections:

1. defn

   ```
   "_id" : ObjectId("8570bebcb7db3"), 
   "fields" : [    {      
   "control" : {   "appearance" : "field-list" },  
   "children" : [ {       "bind" : {      "required" : "yes" },   ...
   ```
2. data

   ```
   "_id" : ObjectId("1570bf18a7db"),
   "defn" : ObjectId("8570bebcb7db3"),
   "data" : {
           "country" : "",
           "age" : 1,
           "age_unit" : "years", 
   },
   "label" : "type"
   ```

that are joined where defn._id =data.defn

How can I write a query to return data.label for defn._id?
The query would be of the form
db.defn.find({ data.label where defn._id= "X"})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MongoDB 3.2, the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) stage can perform the equivalent of a left outer join.

The documentation provides an example of using this operation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-join-with-lookup).

Example using your data:

```
db.defn.insert({
  "_id" : "123456", 
  "some_text" : "main document"
})

db.data.insert( { 
  "defn" : "123456",
  "label" : "data we want to access"
})

db.defn.aggregate( [ 
  { "$lookup" : {
     "from" : "data",
     "localField" : "_id", 
     "foreignField" : "defn",
     "as" : "defns"
    }
  } 
])

// Results:
// { 
//   "_id" : "123456", 
//   "some_text" : "main document", 
//   "defns" : [ { 
//      "_id" : ObjectId("57a2cbbbeb99ff285a1f0893"), 
//      "defn" : "123456", 
//      "label" : "data we want to access" 
//    } ] 
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this module [@coolgk/mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coolgk/mongo), it allows you to join and filter on multiple collections.

### Examples

#### SQL to Mongo Join

Left Join

`SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id`

becomes

```
model.find({}, {
    join: [ { on: 'b_id' } ]
})
```

Result:

```
[{
    _id: '5a8bde4ae2ead929f89f3c42',
    a_name: 'aname1',
    b_id: {
        _id: '5a8bde4ae2ead929f89f3c41',
        b_name: 'bname1'
    }
}, { ... }, ... ]
```

Inner Join with Constraints

`SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.b_id = b.id AND b.b_name = 'bname1'`

becomes

```
model.find({}, {
    join: [ { on: 'b_id', filters: { b_name: 'bname1' } } ]
})
```

Result:

```
[{
    _id: '5a8bdfb05d44ea2a08fa8a4c',
    a_name: 'aname2',
    b_id: {
        _id: '5a8bdfb05d44ea2a08fa8a4b',
        b_name: 'bname2'
    }
}]
```

Inner Join on Mulitple Collections

`SELECT * FROM a, b, c WHERE a.b_id = b.id AND b.c_id = c.id AND c.c_name = 'cname3'`

```
modela.find({}, {
    join: [{
        on: 'b_id',
        join: [{
            on: 'c_id',
            filters: { c_name: 'cname3' }
        }]
    }]
})
```

Result:

```
[{
    _id: '5a8bdfc1b07af22a12cb1f0b',
    a_name: 'aname3',
    b_id: {
        _id: '5a8bdfc1b07af22a12cb1f0a',
        b_name: 'bname3',
        c_id: {
            _id: '5a8bdfc1b07af22a12cb1f09',
            c_name: 'cname3'
        }
    }
}]
```