# MongoDB query to get the cursor of messages from conversations user has participated in?

Tags: mongodb

How would I get the cursor of all of the messages that `a` has participated in and transform `a` into the full username if it is it `alex`?

conversations

```
{ "_id" : "CyiJgeNmxcfRNbnub", "_participants" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : "naZXvcdWdo4QbFDDa", "_participants" : [ "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "ADGuA8PpCS9XKHPoE", "_participants" : [ "a", "c" ] }
```

messages

```
{ "_id" : "9MRBdb4QhoX4nXKtw", "body" : "Asdf", "conversationId" : "CyiJgeNmxcfRNbnub",    "userId" : "a") }
{ "_id" : "sQYxBrmw69pttCs42", "body" : "Yo", "conversationId" : "naZXvcdWdo4QbFDDa",   "userId" : "b") }
{ "_id" : "Hf2vmS54TZbvGbLXT", "body" : "hi", "conversationId" : "ADGuA8PpCS9XKHPoE",   "userId" : "c") }
```

expected result (userId is userId of sender)

```
{ "_id" : "9MRBdb4QhoX4nXKtw", "body" : "Asdf", "conversationId" : "CyiJgeNmxcfRNbnub",    "userId" : "a") }
{ "_id" : "Hf2vmS54TZbvGbLXT", "body" : "hi", "conversationId" : "ADGuA8PpCS9XKHPoE",   "userId" : "c") }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb

Comment: @Wake Thank you so much! I didn't know what to search to find a similar question.