# One to Many Relationship mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a quick question regarding one to many relationships in mongoDB. I have mainly used SQL before this so im getting confused about how to approach relationships. I have viewed all the documentation online and it does not give a good example of how to set up and query a one to many relationship.

Say I have a table of Users and each user has many products. This means that in an SQL situation multiple products in the table would have the same user foreign_key. In mongoDB I have tried to replicate this by placing each users object id into the corresponding product that they are selling much like a foreign key.

Im getting confused on how I would query it. For example how would I do  SELECT * FROM USERS, PRODUCTS WHERE USER_ID = USERFK_ID;?

Ive read about document references, embedded document but its just confusing me more. Does anyone have a straight explanation please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming I understood your question, I will have a users collection and a products collection.

The users collection will contain users and their details. E.g.

{id: '007', name: 'john'}
{id: '010', name: 'paul'}

The products collection will contain products linked to given users. E.g.

{id: '432738', name: 'apple', price: '100', owner: '007'} i.e. owner is john

As pertaining the query, I will do something like this:

db.collection('products').find({owner: user_id_here})

Answer (score -1):

A one-to-many relationship is where the parent document can have many child documents, but the child documents can only have one parent document.

db.artists.insert(
    {
        _id : 3,
        artistname : "Moby",
        albums : [
                    {
                        album : "Play",
                        year : 1999,
                        genre : "Electronica"
                    }, 
                    {
                        album : "Long Ambients 1: Calm. Sleep.",
                        year : 2016,
                        genre : "Ambient"
                    }
                ]
    }
)