# Why leftjoin not working on the laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use this package : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
$data= User::leftJoin('stores', 'stores.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->select('*', 'stores.name AS store_name')
             ->where('status', '=', $status)
             ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
             ->orderBy('users.id')
             ->get();
```

I use join to get store name

I try like that, but when I dd($data), there is no exist store name

How can I solve it?

Comment: Any error message, please show it?

Comment: @Viet Huong Bui, No error

Comment: I think the package does not support `joins` for mongodb. https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/767

Comment: MongoDB is a non-relational database and doesn't support joins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb

Comment: Yes @linktoahref, you right. I found this document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/