# create an get api in nodejs to join two collection based on Id like a left join

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular2-routing

I had two collection I want to perform a kind of left join but want to perform through a router API. I am new to node js.  Can you please help me in it.

Comment: can you explain more what youre trying to do?

Comment: I have a collection say books which has ID and have a second collection say BookSale which has bookID. I want to join both collection based on ID and BookID and get an collection. I want to do it through an API call in router.

Comment: are you wanting the api call to join them or do you want to join them then do the api call?

Comment: when i call an api then it will join both collections and return me a collection or array.

Comment: right so it joins them before. could you provide an example in your question of the layout, so to speak, of what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: dont think so, pratik raj is asking how to do this in the javascript code, not sql code

Answer (score -1):

For me you have three solutions:

1) Code it yourself with Javascript and doing one function with two Api calls (not good at all)

2) You have the [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) solution which is detailed in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb) (seems the right solution)

EDIT:

3) The third solution is also in the [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb) and it looks like this : (what most people are doing but as optimized as option 2), it is not exactly the solution you want since it it doesnt merge both collections at once, but you end up with the same kind of data that you wanted

```
db.collection1.find().forEach(
    function (document) {
        document.collection2 = db.collection2.find( { "collection1": document._id  } ).toArray();
        document.collection3 = db.collection3.find( { "_id": { $in: document.collection3 }  } ).toArray();
    }
);
```

Comment: i only see 2 solutions

Comment: You are right I forgot to write the last solution I am editing