# Best way to query relational collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

For example, i have 2 collections:

First one is named as **"Songs"** and documents in this collection store all metadata about song like `title`, `duration`, `release_date` and other. Beside this, there are also `artist` and `producer` fields, these fields stores ids of relational documents from "Stars" collection.

Example of document in "Songs" collection:

```
{ 
   id: SONG_ID
   title: TITLE, 
   duration: DURATION, 
   release_date: ISO_DATE,
   ...
   artist: STAR_ID
   producer: STAR_ID
}
```

Second one as you guess is **"Stars"** collection and documents in this collection store information about stars like `fullname`, `date_of_birth` and other.

Example of document in "Stars" collection:

```
{ 
   id: STAR_ID
   fullname: FULLNAME, 
   date_of_birth: DATE_OF_BIRTH
   ...
}
```

Suppose i want to find songs that (1 condition) have "love" word in their titles, (2 condition) released in 2017 year and (3 condition) from artists like Rihanna or Zara Larsson. Please note that my problem is different from simple left outer join. Note that in this query 3rd condition relates to information that stored in second collection "Stars", so i dont want just pollute artist and producer fields with information from "Stars" collection but also i want to choose songs with stars just like Rihanna or Zara Larsson.

What is the best and fastest way to do this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: @AdamHarrison  please note that my problem is different from simple left outer join. Note that in this query 3rd condition relates to information that stored in second collection "Stars", so i dont want just pollute artist and producer fields with information from "Stars" collection but also i want to choose songs with stars just like Rihanna or Zara Larsson.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific part of implementation that you have trouble with ? Its hard to know what you've done and what kind of answer you are expecting.

Comment: @Veeram i am open to any answer that could explain me how to build query for this case in best manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

`$match` on `release_date` and `$regex` match on `title`.

`$lookup` to look up `artist` collection followed by `$match` on `fullname` for input values.

```
db.Songs.aggregate([
 { "$match":{ "release_date": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}, title: { $regex: /love$/ } } },
 { "$lookup": {
       "from" : "Stars",
       "localField" : "artist",
       "foreignField" : "_id",
       "as" : "star"
    }
 },
 { "$match" : { "star.fullname" : { "$in": [ "Rihanna", "Zara Larsson" ] } } }
])
```

Regex can make use of index when [anchored](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). Compare with [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Comment: Thanks! I think aggregation pipeline and $match operator is exactly what i was looking for. But as i know second $match wont be able to take advantage of indexes and this is a disappointing point.

Comment: [>> You can read about this here <<](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipeline-optimization)

Comment: You are welcome. The second match can use index. Add `$unwind` between `$lookup` and `$match` and see if it can use index. More here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28140

Comment: in this specific case i think better solution is to do it in 2 steps. In firs step find ids of stars by name from Stars collection. And then in second step find needed songs using ids from first step. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: There is only one way to find out which is test both approaches for your application.