# How to get friend's leaderboard in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Friends Collection

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59e4fbcac23f38cdfa6963a8",
        "friend_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
        "user_id": "59e1d36ad17ad5ad3d0453f7",
        "__v": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-16T18:34:50.875Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e5065f705a90cfa218c9e5",
        "friend_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886edd",
        "user_id": "59e1d36ad17ad5ad3d0453f7",
        "__v": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-10-16T19:19:59.483Z"
    }
]
```

This is my Scores collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed8",
        "score": 19,
        "user_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
        "created_at": "2017-10-13T09:02:10.010Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed9",
        "score": 24,
        "user_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
        "created_at": "2017-10-11T00:56:10.010Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886eda",
        "score": 52,
        "user_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T09:16:10.010Z"
    },
]
```

This is my Users collection.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
        "name": "testuser_0",
        "thumbnail": "path_0"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886edd",
        "name": "testuser_1",
        "thumbnail": "path_1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ee3",
        "name": "testuser_2",
        "thumbnail": "path_2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ee9",
        "name": "testuser_3",
        "thumbnail": "path_3"
    },
]
```

And finally i need list of friends sorted in highscore order for a particular time period (say last 24 hours) with something like this...

```
[
{
"friend_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886ed7",
"friend_name":"test_user_2"
"thumbnail":"image_path",
"highscore":15
},
"friend_id": "59e48f0af8c277d7a8886edd",
"friend_name":"test_user_3"
"thumbnail":"image_path",
"highscore":10
}
]
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I have tried aggregation pipeline but getting quite confused with working with 3 collections.

Comment: The way the collections are done look a lot like a SQL table design. Is there a reason?
A user could have a list of friends and a list of scores all embedded in the same document.
Also MongoDB is not great to join tables like SQL does.

Comment: @A.P. Scores entries would keep increasing with time. A user would have 20-30 score entries per day. In case of Friends it could be embedded but won't the array size of 100-500 entries would be too big and impact performance?

Answer (score 0):

Following your answers, an array size of 500 entries in a document may not be a bad idea to store the friends as you would only store "friends id" and "created" in each entry. It saves having a collection.
You would not have too much performances issues if you project the data in your query by selecting only the fields you want.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specified-fields-only

For the score that increase of 30 per day; it depends what type of query you do.
It would take a while to reach the 2MB limit per the document by adding 30 scores per day.

regarding joining the different collections there is a stack overflow question about it:

[How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

or

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

You will need to use the aggregation framework from mongoDB to use if; not just a find command.

Comment: I got it working using look up aggregation. My current query time is around 400ms to get friend's leaderboard for last 24 hours when i had the collections separately with 10,000 users and 100,000 scores entries. 
No idea with what speed it would increase I guess i should try the array way as well to compare.

Comment: Bench marking different collection design is always a good idea.