# How to get single field from different collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having two collections 'MotorDetails' and 'PersonDetails'.Person Id is present is my both collections. I required all items from PersonDetails and only Manufacturer Name from MotorDetails for each person Id. how to join collections in mongodb?
I am very new to mongodb so Please help me with this scenario

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.PersonDetails.aggregate([
{$lookup:{
  from: "MotorDetails",
  localField:"personId",
  foreignField:"personIdEquivalentOnMotorDetails",
  as:"PersonToManufacturer"

}}

])
```

Search on stackoverflow(check existing questions) and Google if you want to learn something new. Do not post direct questions where answers are already present on stackoverflow. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

You should read , try out yourself and post here only if you stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB being a NoSQL database does not support concept of relationships
Alternatively it facilitates defining relationship using embedded documents.

Also MongoDB has added `$lookup` operator which is used to perform left outer join operations into MongoDB Database as a part of aggregation pipeline.

For more detailed description regarding `$lookup` operator please refer documentation as mentioned into following URL

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/