# How to port a JOIN from mysql to Mongoose / MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables with this format:

> Table 1 - domains
>
> tag0 | tag1 | url | title | domain
>
> Table 2 -favicons
>
> domain | favicon_local

I do a basic join to get the data that I need as such:

```
  const query = `SELECT domains.*, favicons.favicon_local `
              + `FROM domains `
              + `JOIN favicons ON domains.domain=favicons.domain `
              + `ORDER BY domains.tag0`;
```

I want to create the same table in Mongoose/MongoDB.

How would I do this port.  Should I just create a single Schema with all 6 columns?

And then somehow take the JOIN data and insert it directly into Mongoose?

Comment: If this is one time thing then you already answered your question. If this is periodic thing and you want to emulate SQL join mongo then this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb