# Join collection on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, mongoose-schema

I have two tables in Mongo - `users` and `departments`, and we want to get users and the related department (using `department_id` from users table) .

Using MySQL, I can just make a simple join on department_id.

But, how can I do the same in MongoDB?

Comment: You should read [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) && [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)