# Get data from two different collections in mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am new in mongodb database, i want to fetch data from two different collections ( like in mysql use of joins) then how can we do this in mongodb ? Here my collections data

```
First collection 

{
    "id": "5b67dbf20b9f9d2830ccaf40",
    "title": "Some Text",
    "author": "John Doe"
}


Second collection 

{
    "id": "5b67dbyd48btr9jexya8ehd8",
    "pid": "5b67dbf20b9f9d2830ccaf40",
    "salary": "50000"
}
```

Comment: Please look into $lookUp.

Ref Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Update your `NewSchema` as:

```
var NewSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    pid: {
            type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: `Firstcollection`
        }
    });
```

You can solve it using [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) from mongoose.

```
SecondCollection.find({})
.populate('pid')
.exec(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Hope it solves your query!!

Comment: not working , showing record of first collection only , i want to to get data where both id ( id in first collection and pid in second collection ) matchs

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?
Can you share the schema with data in question and the expected result?

Comment: @NehaGupta If the above query is not working then I think you don't have first and esecond collection linked using **ref**.

Comment: i want to fetch records from both collections. Thats it!

Comment: Can you post your model schema?

Comment: Here is my code of model , ( my collections names are firstcollection and second collection)

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique: true
    },
 phone : String
 });

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('Firstcollection', UserSchema);



var NewSchema = mongoose.Schema({});
const Newuser = module.exports = mongoose.model('Secondcollection', NewSchema);

Comment: Update your NewSchema as I have added it in question and try the given query now.