# Mongo db query For join queries

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two different object

1. User
2. UserGroup

**User**

```
{
          _id:1,
          Name:'name',
          Usergroup:
      [

                        {
                                '$ref' : 'UserGroup',
                                '$id' : 1
                         },

                         {
                                '$ref' : 'UserGroup',
                                '$id' : 2
                        }]


 }
```

**UserGroup**

```
{
                         _id:1,
                          name: 'admin'
                  },{
                        _id:2,
                         name: 'admin1'
 }
```

I need to get usergroup collection along with list of users can anyone help me on writing join query please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup` in mongo to join two collections.

```
  db.user_collection_name.aggregate(
{
    $project: { 
        group_id: {
          $map: { 
             input: { 
                  $map: {
                      input:"$userGroup",
                      in: {
                           $arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$$this"}, 1]
                      },
                  }
             },
             in: "$$this.v"}},
             "name":1
        }
}, 
    {$lookup:
         {
           from: userGroup_collection_name,
           localField: "group_id",
           foreignField: _id,
           as: users
         }
    })
```

**Explanation:**
Within the aggregator, a DBRef BSON type can be handled like an object, with two or three fields (ref, id, and DB). Therefore we need to abstract key, the value from dbref field. Therefore we need `$project` function to take `Id` then we can `$lookup` using that Id.

Comment: I need to get usergroups with list of users for a group. In user collection usergroup is in array.. I tried your example  getting error 'field path names may not start with $'

Comment: Updated my answer kindly test now.