# How to connect to collections by nested fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am struggling with some query in MongoDB. Let's say I have standings collection which looks like

```
{
   "competitions: {id: "1", name:"someLeague"},
   "standings": [
      {
         "type": "TOTAL",
         "table": [
            {
               "position": "1",
               "team": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "XYZ"
               },  
               won: "1",
               draw: "2",
               lost: "3",
               points: "4",
            },
            {
               "position": "2",
               "team": {
                  "id": "321",
                  "name": "ABC"
               }
                      ...
```

And the fixtures collection  which looks like

```
{
   matchDay: "YYYY-MM-DD",
   homeTeam: {id:  "123", name:"ABC"}, 
   awayTeam: {id:  "321", name:"XYZ"},
}
```

Is it possible to connect this two collection this way that field "homeTeam" in fixtures collection will contain all information including points, won games etc. from standings where type would be total? And same thing  with the field awayTeam, with the proviso that information of team would be from array where standings type is away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no means in MongoDB to reference a document of collection A in collection B so that `find` queries on collection B automatically provide attributes of the referenced document. However, as of MongoDB 3.2 it is possible to use `$lookup` command as part of an `aggregation` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511166/3976662) to JOIN (similar to standard SQL) over multiple collections during the query. In your case, you can consider using `$lookup` in conjunction with `$unwind` - similar [to the example in the MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array). Spring Data Mongo supports `$lookup` [since 1.10](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).