# I want to know advanced mongodb aggregation

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation

I want to know how to make MongoDB query same for this mysql query

```
"SELECT * FROM `folders` `F` JOIN `files` `I` ON I._id IN F.filesId;"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.folders.aggregate([
{ 
    $lookup: { 
        from: "files",
        localField: "_id", 
        foreignField: "filesId", //_id is ObjectId() so  filesId fields on 
        as: "docs"               //  files table mustbe ObjectId Save
    } 
}
])
```

"https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/"