# How to only show the clients records/data when they log in?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having difficulties showing the data only for the correct client. So on my web app, I have a page where only the signed-in user can see the blogs they have uploaded, but when I sign into email A, I can still see what email B has uploaded. It doesn't matter what email I sign into, for some reason it's as if they're all sharing the account. I would like to know how to distinguish their data for that correct user. I have 3 collections. I have one for their private info, their Blog, and where the sessions are stored.

I have tried embedding the "blog" schema into their private info schema because I thought that would solve it, but then I figured out that every time I uploaded a new sub doc, the parent needs to be updated too since I have some properties required. I took this idea out. There has to be a way to correlate the collections right? I keep asking myself, "how am I going to connect the blog ids from this collection to the collection of the correct users id?" Please help, thanks!

Comment: you can set an id every post and query only the post match the user id.

Comment: That is what I am having difficulties with.

Comment: @kimdecastro Just now I actually tried to query the id only on the frontend in my services, but it's still not functioning properly.

Comment: see the result in console. check what the server side giving you. if not try to change the code a bit if its updating or there's a changes.

Comment: I still can't seem to solve this, sadly.

Comment: I have found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb