# What is the best Database Model for Directed Graph Data structure?

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, database-design, nosql

### Relational database systems or document-oriented database systems?

[image: a family tree]

If you want to choose between SQL and NoSQL which database systems will you prefer for **a family tree,** 
Are there any advantages of sheme-free database system over a relational database in a family tree.

Comment: Database recommendations are specifically outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: If your choice was between PostgreSQL and a graph database like Neo4J I could see why you might have a dilemma. But it's hard to understand why you think a document store like MongoDB is appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely PostgreSQL is a better choice in this case, a family tree will require joins and meanwhile MongoDb does not support joins, checkout a previous QandA on how to perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb) but with Relational database you do not have to worry about joins.