# How to join MongoDB with DBRef

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two documents with a DBRef relation between those documents.

Task document:

```json
{
  "_id": 77,
  "title": "Test title",
  "status": "in-progress",
  "reporter": {
    "$ref": "User",
    "$id": ObjectId("5daf022549a36e319879f357"),
    "$db": "test"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "project": {
    "$ref": "Project",
    "$id": 30,
    "$db": "gsc"
  }
}
```

User Document:

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5daf022549a36e319879f357"),
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "is_active": true,
  "firstName": "user-1"
}
```

I tried below query but I didn't get proper result

```js
db.Task.findOne($lookup:
  {
    from: User,
    localField: reporter,
    foreignField: reporter._id,
    as: User_Task
  }
)
```

How to perform the JOIN? Also, want to both document all data?
*I want data from Task Document and suggest how to join with project field.*

Need this kind of result:

```json
{
    "_id" : 77,
    "title" : "Test title",
    "status" : "in-progress"
    "reporter" : 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5daf022549a36e319879f357"),
        "username" : "user1",
        "email" : "test@gmail.com"
        "is_active" : true,
        "firstName" : "user-1"
    },
    "priority" : "high",
    "project" : {}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: No, This does not work for me this was for match records and i want a relational records. hope you understand.

Comment: Sure, I just saved the information from @lucferbux before it disappears - it was flagged for deletion.

Comment: I saw that, I also did fixed some typesetting for you. What do you mean exactly by the *text in italics*?

Comment: It means I want to fire query on task document (db.Task.find({})) and join project and reporter document in the same DTO response, Do you Understand?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `$lookup` should do the trick. You just need to supply `reporter.$id` to the field `localField`

```
db.task.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "reporter.$id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "reporter"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$reporter"
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bFJHVUuKrjO) for your reference.