# How do I reference a field from child table to parent table in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have two collections. Let's say, I want to search all the names of people in Parent table where place in child table = "Amsterdam". In SQL this would be something like this,

```
SELECT p.name FROM ParentTable p INNER JOIN ChildTable c ON p._id = c.parent_id WHERE place = "Amsterdam";
```

Following is the database schema,
[image: Database Schema]

Now, I am new to the world of NoSQL databases. How should I structure my MongoDB database to achieve something similar to the above?
Should I nest the collections or is there a way to reference the collections like the Foreign Key in SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like foreign key. And you can't join multiple collections either.
What you can do is use $lookup pipeline operator in aggregation.
Already answered here => [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)