# Mongo template left join between two queries

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

In a spring project, I'm using **reactive** mongodb with mongo template to return a result of type Report class.

```
    var res1 = (Flux<Report>) template.find(query1, ReportFactory.getReport(reportType).getClass());

    var res2 = (Flux<Report>) template.find(query2, ReportFactory.getReport(reportType).getClass());
```

I want a way to find the left join between two result using mongo template **without using java.**
For example:

if `res1 = {Rep1,Rep2,Rep3]`and: `res2 = {Rep2,Rep5}`

the left join between them should be **Rep2**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)